# How do I match samples with their predictions when doing inference with PyTorch's DistributedSampler?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, pytorch, multi-gpu

I have trained a torch model for NLP tasks and would like to perform some inference using a multi GPU machine (in this case with two GPUs).
Inside the processing code, I use this

```
dataset = TensorDataset(encoded_dict['input_ids'], encoded_dict['attention_mask'])
sampler = DistributedSampler(
    dataset, num_replicas=args.nodes * args.gpus, rank=args.node_rank * args.gpus +    gpu_number, shuffle=False
)
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, sampler=sampler)
```

For those familiar with NLP, `encoded_dict` is the output from the `tokenizer.batch_encode_plus` function where the tokenizer is an instance of `transformers.BertTokenizer`.

The issue I’m having is that when I call the code through the `torch.multiprocessing.spawn` function, each GPU is doing predictions (i.e. inference) on a subset of the full dataset, and saving the predictions separately; for example, if I have a dataset with 1000 samples to predict, each GPU is predicting 500 of them. As a result, I have no way of knowing which samples out of the 1000 were predicted by which GPU, as their order is not preserved, therefore the model predictions are meaningless as I cannot trace each of them back to their input sample.

I have tried to save the dataloader instance (as a pickle) together with the predictions and then extracting the input_ids by using `dataloader.dataset.tensors`, however this requires a tokeniser decoding step which I rather avoid, as the tokenizer will have slightly changed the text (for example double whitespaces would be removed, words with dashes will have been split and so on).
What is the cleanest way to save the input text samples together with their predictions when doing inference in distributed mode, or alternatively to keep track of which prediction refers to which sample?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, basically your dataset returns for an index `idx` `[data,label]` during training and `[data]` during inference. The issue with this is that the `idx` is not preserved by the `dataloader` object, so there is no way to obtain the `idx` values for the minibatch after the fact.

One way to handle this issue is to define a very simple custom dataset object that also returns `[data,id]` instead of only `data` during inference. Probably the easiest way to do this is to make the dataset return a dictionary object with keys `id` and `data`. The dictionary return type is convenient because Pytorch *collates* (converts data structures to batches) this type automatically, otherwise you'd have to define a custom `collate_fn`  and pass it to the dataloader object, which is itself not very hard but is an extra step.

In any case, here's I would define a new dataset object as follows which should be almost a one-to-one substitute for your current dataset (I believe):

```
def TensorDictDataset(torch.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self,ids,attention_mask):
        self.ids = ids
        self.mask = attention_mask

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.ids)

    def __getitem(self,idx):
        datum = {
            "mask": self.mask[idx],
            "id":ids[idx]
                }
        return datum
```

The only change you'll then have to make is that rather than returning `mask` your dataset will now return `dict{"mask":mask,"id":id}` so you'll have to parse that appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answer. I have done further debugging and found another solution and wanted to post it.
Your solution is quite elegant (there was one minor misunderstanding, in that the predictions contain only the predicted labels and not the data contrary to what you understood, but this doesn't affect your answer anyway). Mask is NLP is also something else, and instead of having the mask tokens together with predictions I would like to have the untokenized text string. This is not so easy to achieve because the splitting of the data into different GPUs happens AFTER the tokenisation, however I believe that with a slight adaptation to your answer it could work.
However, I’ve done some further debugging and I’ve noticed that the data are not actually randomly split across GPUs as I thought. If I set `shuffle=False` in the `DistributedSampler` then this happens:
in the case of two GPUs, GPU 0 and GPU 1, all the samples with even index (starting from 0) will be passed to GPU 0, and all those with odd index will be passed to GPU 1.
So for example, if you have 10 samples, whose indices are [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], then samples 0, 2, 4, 6, 8 will go to GPU 0 and samples 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 will to go GPU 1. Therefore this allows me to map the predictions back to the original text string samples by just using this ordering. Not sure if this is the best solution, as keeping the original text string next to its prediction would be ideal, but at least it works.

N.B. Special case: As the two GPUs must be passed the SAME number of inputs, if the number of inputs is an odd number, for example we have 9 samples with indices [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], then GPU 0 will be passed samples 0, 2, 4, 6, 8 and GPU 1 will be passed samples 1, 3, 5, 7, 0 (in this exact order). In other words, the first sample with index 0 is repeated at the very end of the dataset to make sure each GPU has the same number of samples, in which case we can then write some codes which drops the last prediction from GPU 1 as it is redundant.